# Regular Expression to replace substring occurrences when not surrounded by square brackets

Tags: regex, r

Lets say I have the following string vector:

```
x <- c("this!", "is!", "not my name[!]!", "Understrand[!] Mate!", 
"Because!I[!] said so!")
```

I need a way of replacing the exclamation marks "!" with "!\n" but only if the exclamation mark is not surrounded by square brackets. So the output would look like this:

```
"this!\n"
"is!\n"
"not my name[!]!\n"
"Understrand[!] Mate!\n"
"Because!\nI[!] said so!\n"
```

I've been playing around and just can't figure it out.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Tony B.

Comment: What about `"aa[!bb"` or `aa!]bb`?

Comment: @Merek The solution by rcs below solves my problem exactly; I've asked him/her if it can be generalised to include the two cases you mentioned. If not, I'll still accept his answer as it solves my issue exactly :)

Comment: You can maybe avoid this issue by separating the formatting (line breaks) from the content.  `strwrap` will help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a perl style regex with a negative look-behind `(?<!pattern)` and negative look-ahead `(?!pattern)` assertion:

```
R> gsub("(?<!\\[)\\!(?!\\])", "!\n", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "this!\n"                   "is!\n"                    
[3] "not my name[!]!\n"         "Understrand[!] Mate!\n"   
[5] "Because!\nI[!] said so!\n"
```

**Edit:** @Mareks test cases require a Boolean "or" ("|"):

```
R> gsub("(?<!\\[)\\!|\\!(?!\\])", "!\n", c("aa[!bb", "aa!]bb"), perl=TRUE)
[1] "aa[!\nbb" "aa!\n]bb"
```

Comment: This works perfectly in the cases I've given, thank you. @Marek gives the cases of "aa[!bb" and "aa!]bb" which testing this against wouldn't work. I am happy to accept this answer just as it is given it solves my problem, but is there any way to generalise it to include cases as above?

Comment: how about this: gsub("(?<!\\[)!|!(?!\\])", "!\n", x, perl=TRUE)